# Window.location.href Set no-follow

Tags: javascript

Newbie Question:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#phone").click(function(){
        window.location.href = window.location.href + "&set=phone";
    });
});
```

I want to set this to nofollow. I dont' want google to index the link that says &set=phone. How would I do it ?

Comment: To clarify something - are you expecting that by doing this, the url you've specified with `&set=phone` will never be visited by anyone other than someone clicking on `#phone`?  If so, why?  Hopefully you're not triggering something to happen server side with a GET request?  That would potentially be very bad... it wouldn't surprise me if some browsers prefetch such links on the off chance someone clicks on it.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want Google to index a URL, then mention it in `robots.txt` or include a `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">` in it.

The `nofollow` relationship only applies to links (and your JavaScript is not a link) and doesn't mean "Don't index this" anyway (it means "this link is not an endorsement").

---

The use of the word "set" implies that you are sending the server an instruction to store some data. This would make it a [non-idempotent](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) request and you should not use GET for it. If that is the case, then submit a form with the POST method instead of assigning a value to `location.href`. Google won't submit such forms.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the issue around GET/POST in an answer - I think it's an important point here.